# get request.Body param value .net core 2

Tags: json, .net-core, aws-lambda

I'm receiving a json object as request body content, like:

```
{
  "reportID": "C4239"
}
```

When i try to get the value of "reportID" it doesn't seem to be a method like `request.Body.value` or something. How could i get the param's value of this json object?.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public class desResponse
{
    public string reportId;
}

desResponse reqObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<desResponse>(request.Body);
var objId = reqObj.reportId.ToString();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: request.Body is of Type Stream. How can you Deserialize Stream type to your data model.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ASP.NET Core doesn't let you just capture 'raw' data in any meaningful way just by way of method parameters.

One way or another you need to do some custom processing of the `Request.Body` to get the raw data out and then deserialize it.

You can use below code to process the Request Body:-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction()
    {
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                var body = reader.ReadToEnd();

                YourDataModel reqObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourDataModel>(body);
                var objId = reqObj.reportId;
            }
        // Do some work
    }
```

You can get the details on below link:-
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers